# Dwolla account Integration with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dwolla

can anyone please help me out here.I am new to ROR. Can anyone please tell me how to implement dwolla in ruby on rails 3.0.1. I am actually not getting any help from anywhere.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at [this gem](https://github.com/Dwolla/dwolla-ruby)?

Comment: thanks for your response. I actually already have gone through this site and i had no idea how to implement dwolla from the site.

Comment: Thanks for your question.  Likewise, after reading the info on Dwolla's site, am still looking for a complete RoR use-example. How do those 'bits' of Ruby fit into my app?  Now to spend a long-day experimenting, to get a billable hour or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dwolla has [a site](https://developers.dwolla.com/dev) that explains everything.

On that page, they:

- have the entire API [documented](https://developers.dwolla.com/dev/docs)
- outline the [libraries](https://developers.dwolla.com/dev/libraries) that are available to developers
- provide [ruby sample code](https://developers.dwolla.com/dev/samples/ruby)
- make it easy to [generate your own token](https://developers.dwolla.com/dev/token)